# Is there any specific convension/best practices for perl module creation?

Tags: perl, oop

On what basis Files should be classified(Right now each of my Files are for specific task/section), the maximum number of lines in a file, File design for object oriented perl etc.

If there is any good links for the same please provide me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think basic OOP principles apply here.

CPAN distribution creation conventions define for example your directory structure lib for modules/classes, t for tests, README and so on, but not how you define classes. Also, there is [`perlmodstyle`](http://p3rl.org/perlmodstyle):

> This document attempts to describe the Perl Community's "best practice" for writing Perl modules. It extends the recommendations found in perlstyle , which should be considered required reading before reading this document.
>
> While this document is intended to be useful to all module authors, it is particularly aimed at authors who wish to publish their modules on CPAN.
>
> The focus is on elements of style which are visible to the users of a module, rather than those parts which are only seen by the module's developers. However, many of the guidelines presented in this document can be extrapolated and applied successfully to a module's internals.
>
> This document differs from perlnewmod in that it is a style guide rather than a tutorial on creating CPAN modules. It provides a checklist against which modules can be compared to determine whether they conform to best practice, without necessarily describing in detail how to achieve this.

In fact, it's not required to use OOP at all. There are many successful classical modules which just export subroutines.